# UITapGesture Works only a part

Tags: iphone, uitapgesturerecognizer

Recently i tried to create a custom segmentedControl where i had three views in it.

WHILE I WAS TOUCHING FIRST HALF OF THE VIEW THE tapGesture WORKED. But the rest half dint respond.

My frame of the segment is:

segment.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100) ;

And the frame of the UIView is:

view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 100, 40)];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the height of the frame to 200 And then it will work:

```
segment.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200) ;
```

Reason: Your height of the view is less when compared.

Comment: Wait i will check. Seems  logical

Answer (score 0):

Put Your view frame like this it will work for you..Because you add Segment with height 100 from y=0, So you can set view frame after y = 100..

view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 110, 100, 40)];